# Multiline titles in TeeChart Legend?

Tags: xamarin.ios, teechart

Is it possible to have the title of a series span more than one line in the chart legend? I can't seem to find a way to get a reference to the UILabel, or whatever control is used to display the series name within the legend.

Answer (score 0):

What about subscribing the *GetLegendText* event in your chart and add line breaks in the text (*e.Text* argument)?

Comment: Hello. I've tried adding line breaks to the texts already. What happens is that the text gets truncated at the linebreak. So instead of (say) "A rather long series description", when I add a linebreak after "long", I only get "A rather long" inside the legend.

Comment: @Yiangos yes, series doesn't resize to fit multi-line items. You should replace the legend with Annotation or Rectangle tools, for example.

Comment: @Yiangos you could also create your own custom legend as Christopher Ireland explained here: http://www.teechart.net/support/viewtopic.php?t=8156

Comment: The custom legend example is for the .NET version. Will something like that work for monotouch? Also, I will be looking into the "Annotation/rectangle tools you suggested as well. However if you could provide a pointer so that I could start searching, I'd be grateful.

Comment: @Yiangos yes, most .NET examples should be the same for Xamarin.iOS/MonoTouch as the .NET code is the engine of TeeChart for Xamarin.iOS. My recomendation is that you search at our .NET forum (http://www.teechart.net/support/index.php) for Annotation and Rectangle tool examples with custom positioning.